# What does " warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock" means?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one collection, say "resource.pool", which emulates the resource pool.
There are 2 states of resource:
1. FREE, it means we can acquire this resource, by setting its flag to OCCUPIED (using findAndModify)
2. OCCUPIED, it means the resource is already occupied by another process. But if it is in OCCUPIED state for too long, we can acquire it by checking if `currentTime - lastFreeTime >= expiredAge`.

In order to acquire one resources, I plan 1 query: expiredAge is 600000 msec.

```
db.resource.pool.findAndModify({
 groupId:"groupId",
 $or :[{state:"FREE"},{state:{$ne:"FREE"}, $where:"currentTime - this.lastFreeTime >= 600000"}]
},{state:"OCCUPIED, lastFreeTime:currentTime})
```

That query is always shown in mongodb.log file, and generated for 1-3 warning per second. What is the meaning of this warning?

Note that I use $where which evaluate the javascript. I also have created index of groupId and state.

Comment: Can I strongly suggest that you externally evaluate another value for the 6 millisecond difference and pass that in as a direct value rather than using JavaScript evaluation. Mainly so you could use an index and also to see if your problem goes away when you do so.

Comment: @NeilLunn: yeah, actually I already tried so (instead of using $where, i use "lastFreeTime":{$lte:currentTime-600000}, and it still appears at the log file.

Comment: So have you indexed `lastFreeTime` as well in the compound index? That would seem to make sense. What we are trying to do here is avoid the "lag" time on the "query" component of the update by making it work efficiently.

Comment: Neil's right that you should try to speed up the operation in order to get rid of the log messages. The warning is more or less harmless except that it usually indicates high load or queries that aren't using indexes but should be.